# React Smooth DND Library causing and 'illegal invocation error'

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, jsdom

Libraries

- Jest
- React Testing Library

Description
   When I run the test for the component that uses smooth-dnd by itself. It works fine. However, when I run all my tests, I get this illegal invocation error.

Node.js from the jsdom library

```
Object.defineProperty(Node.prototype, "childNodes", {
get() {
if (!this || !module.exports.is(this)) {
  throw new TypeError("Illegal invocation"); // Error here
}

return utils.getSameObject(this, "childNodes", () => {
  return utils.tryWrapperForImpl(this[impl]["childNodes"]);
});
 },

 enumerable: true,
 configurable: true
});
```

This is the error.

```
Test suite failed to run

TypeError: Illegal invocation

  at Node.get [as childNodes] (node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/generated/Node.js:423:13)
  at Node.get (node_modules/smooth-dnd/dist/index.js:1:11462)
  at node_modules/smooth-dnd/dist/index.js:1:11356
  at node_modules/smooth-dnd/dist/index.js:1:96
  at Object.<anonymous> (node_modules/smooth-dnd/dist/index.js:1:195)
  at node_modules/react-smooth-dnd/dist/index.js:1:145`
```

It seems that smooth-dnd calls jsdom and jsdom is throwing an exception. But it only happens when I run all my tests. When I run them individually, they work fine.

What is the Node for in jsdom?

according to the code this line is catching the error `(!this || !module.exports.is(this)`

Why would Node be undefined when I run all the tests but defined when I run the tests individually?

Is there a possible solution to this or should I try a different drag and drop library.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide the code you are using to test, as well as the working test code.

Answer (score 1):

For those (like me) that #36 didn't work, and also #52, I had to spend a few hours on it just to figure it out.

Inside the `smooth-dnd` lib, there's a `polyfill.ts` that does, baiscally:

```js
// Overwrites native 'firstElementChild' prototype.
// Adds Document & DocumentFragment support for IE9 & Safari.
// Returns array instead of HTMLCollection.
(function(constructor) {
    if (constructor &&
        constructor.prototype &&
        constructor.prototype.firstElementChild == null) {
        Object.defineProperty(constructor.prototype, 'firstElementChild', {
            get: function() {
                var node, nodes = this.childNodes, i = 0;
                while (node = nodes[i++]) {
                    if (node.nodeType === 1) {
                        return node;
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
})(Node || Element);
```

And that polyfill just aplly up to IE9 and Safari 8, also Chrome versions up to 29. Since we're on v.289 of chrome and others, that's not even usefull. In my (updated) package, I just removed this function and every Jest test works fine.

I took the time to wrap everything up to my own way, removing the `smooth-dnd` dependency and making everything to .js.

If you're still struggling with that issue, come take a look at my solution at [vue-dndrop](https://github.com/amendx/vue-dnd).

If that, somehow helps you, let me know.